# iOS hybrid app WKWebView soft keyboard covering input fields sometimes

Tags: ios, input, uikeyboard, wkwebview, hybrid

I am using a WKWebView as my web container on my iOS 8+ hybrid app.

When an input field in the web container is focused and the soft keyboard comes up, the web view scrollview *usually* scrolls up automatically.

However, sometimes the web view scrollview does not scroll up, and hides the input field behind the soft keyboard. Only when I begin typing into the soft keyboard does the web view scrollview scroll up.

The only solution I can think of is getting the input field position in the web view, and overriding the automatic scrolling provided by iOS. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and I was able to solve it by waiting until the keyboard finished animating/sliding up, then taking the height of the element that was focused on, then shifting the screen so that the bottom of that element was a set distance above the top of the keyboard.

It requires a bit of math, but it is doable!